# Which LTS is good to start using Ubuntu?

Tags: lts

I am a beginner and wanted to know which LTS is good to start using the Ubuntu. I would prefer a stable version so that I have to do minimal tweaks.

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use the most recent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a beginner myself and started using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for my development at [JustDoc](https://justdoc.com/), which is the latest LTS. I feel it is pretty stable and should be good for most functionalities.

Obviously, you will need to provide more information on what your intended use out of Ubuntu is, so that a correct LTS can be recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Go with the latest LTS version because:

- It wouldn't have made it to LTS, if there are any stability issues.
- If there are any flaws in it, people are still using it which makes it more likely problems will be fixed in a shorter time period.

In the past I've used every LTS version and no major problems have arisen.

Answer (score 4):

You can visit the [official website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and download the latest  stable LTS version and usually with Ubuntu no "tweaks" are required unless you want to.